# How to change \bar properties in a customized latex symbol

Tags: graphics, amsmath

I'd just created a simple customized symbol to place a `\bar` over `\otimes`, as following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myotimes}{
    \mathbin{\text{\scalebox{0.9}{$\bar{{\otimes}}$}}}
}

\begin{document}

$\myotimes(a,b,c)$ 

\end{document}
```

But the applied bar is too short and thin (It is not easily readable without zooming in.)

**How can I consider the customization of both `\bar`'s length and thickness in `\myotimes` command?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\newcommand{\newotimes}{\overset{\rule[-.5 ex]{.6em}{.2ex}}{\otimes}}
```

The first argument specifies the height; the second argument is the length; the third specifies the thickness.

Comment: Thanks... But changing the first argument has no effect on the height.

Comment: Changing to 0 raises the bar slightly. Changing to 0.5 raises it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using the `\widebar` extensible accent from `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<5><6><7><8><9><10>
<10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>
mathx10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\barotimes}{
    \mathbin{\scalebox{0.9}{$\mkern2.4mu\overline{{\mkern-2.4mu\otimes\mkern-2.4mu}}\mkern2.4mu$}}}

\begin{document}

 $ \barotimes(a,b,c)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think the bar is too thin, but you can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\myotimes}{%
  \mathbin{\text{%
    \scalebox{0.9}{%
      $
       \mspace{1.5mu}
       \overline{\mspace{-1.5mu}\otimes\mspace{-1.5mu}}
       \mspace{1.5mu}
      $%
    }%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

$\myotimes(a,b,c)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `\scalebox`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm using both `\otimes` and this bar-version. As my supervisor had analyzed a draft of my report, he asserted that a reader will be in trouble to detect the difference between these two symbols and wanted me to make the bar more clear!